# sort doubly linked list in alphabetical order java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list, alphabetical

I'm learning Java right now and I want to sort doubly linked list in alphabetical order and have the user input a letter or words. Can someone help me with it?

This is the code I have so far.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList {
    String data;
    Node next;
    Node prev;
    Node head;

    public void Node(String data, Node next, Node prev, Node head) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.head = head;
    }

    //inserts new Node at front of the list. 
    public void push(String newData) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newData);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-doubly-linked-list/ and www.geeksforgeeks.org/quicksort-for-linked-list/

Comment: @Saravana but that's for C not for java.

Comment: Both implementations are available in the website, just navigate to C tab

Comment: @Saravana these are for int though.